# Count how many times an element appears in an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap, enumerable

This is the array that is going to be processed:

```
[{:name => "blake"}, {:name => "blake"}, {:name => "ashley"}]
```

and I would like the result to be like this:

```
[{:name => "blake", :count => 2}, {:name => "ashley", :count => 1}]
```

I created a new hash called "count" then i used `.each` to iterate through the array and then `count[:count] += 1`, but it's not giving me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done with built-in library calls like this:

```
a = [{:name => "blake"}, {:name => "blake"}, {:name => "ashley"}]
a.group_by(&:itself)                   # group all of the identical elements together
 .map{|k, v| k.merge(count: v.length)} # add the "count" element to the hash
```

### Explanation

`.group_by(&:itself)` will take all the identical components and put them in a hash together under the same key:

```
>> h = a.group_by(&:itself)
=> {
     {:name=>"blake"}  => [{:name=>"blake"}, {:name=>"blake"}],
     {:name=>"ashley"} => [{:name=>"ashley"}]
    }
```

Notice how the first entry in the hash has an array of two identical elements, and the second entry has an array of one element. To create counts of those, we can use the `.length` method on the arrays in the hash's values:

```
>> k, v = h.first
>> v
=> [{:name=>"blake"}, {:name=>"blake"}]

>> v.length
=> 2
```

Then we can use `.map` to apply that code to every element in the hash:

```
>> h.map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}.to_h
=> {
     {:name=>"blake"}=>2,
     {:name=>"ashley"}=>1
   }
```

Finally, `.merge` will take two hashes and piece them together into a single hash:

```
>> {:name=>"blake"}.merge({:count => 1})
=> {:name=>"blake", :count=>1}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the v.length part. can you explain why we re counting the length of the value?

Answer (score 3):

Here the new [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) introduced with **Ruby 2.7.0** comes in hand:

```
h = [{:name => "blake"}, {:name => "blake"}, {:name => "ashley"}]

h.tally.map {|k, v| k.merge({count: v}) }
#=> [{:name=>"blake", :count=>2}, {:name=>"ashley", :count=>1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three main ways of doing this.

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

That is what @user12341234 has done in his or her answer.

**Use a counting hash**

If `arr` is your array,

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:name]] += 1 }.
    map { |name, count| { :name=>name, :count=>count } }
  #=> [{:name=>"blake", :count=>2}, {:name=>"ashley", :count=>1}]
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for details.

**Use the form of `Hash#update` (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.**

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:name]=>1) { |_,o,n| o+n } }.
    map { |name, count| { :name=>name, :count=>count } }
  #=> [{:name=>"blake", :count=>2}, {:name=>"ashley", :count=>1}]
```

See the doc [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) for details.

Notice that last line is the same for #2 and #3.

I cannot say that one of these approaches is preferable to the others.